# Googlemaps v2 'Error inflaing class fragment"

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, fragment

I am having real troubles getting even a simple Map app to open (both on AVD virtual device or on real Android phones). Using Eclipse / ADT up to date installation.

The code is more-or-less straight from a book chapter on GoogleMaps v2 ('Android Application Development Cookbook' by Wei-Meng Lee / Wrox). A few weeks ago before a SSD failure, I briefly had similar code running. I have left the code from the book untouched - downloaded / imported etc. Other simple helloworld and other apps run fine on the AVD etc.

I have:

- added the google-play-services-lib
- got my GoogleMapsv2 API key - leaving the package name unchanged
- trawled through loads of articles / questions here and elsewhere and compared code / checked for errors.

Nothing seems to help. After 4 weeks of frustration I am now begging for help (and possibly forgiveness if this is a simple mistake!)

My Manifest file reads:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="net.learn2develop.googlemaps"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="19"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<permission
    android:name="net.learn2develop.googlemaps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="net.learn2develop.googlemaps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="net.learn2develop.googlemaps.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="my_API_Key_was_put_here"

         />

    <!-- next meta data tag added after consulting stack overflow forums -->

    <meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />



</application>

</manifest>
```

My Layout reads like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"  >

<fragment
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"        
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />


</LinearLayout>
```

My Mainactivity.java is as follows.

```
package net.learn2develop.googlemaps;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
GoogleMap map;

private static final LatLng GOLDEN_GATE_BRIDGE = new LatLng(37.828891,
        -122.485884);
private static final LatLng APPLE = new LatLng(37.3325004578, -122.03099823);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // alt is ..map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();


    map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    if (map == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Google Maps not available", 
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case R.id.menu_sethybrid:
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        break;

    case R.id.menu_showtraffic:
        map.setTrafficEnabled(true);
        break;

    case R.id.menu_zoomin:
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomIn());
        break;

    case R.id.menu_zoomout:
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomOut());
        break;

    case R.id.menu_gotolocation:
        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(GOLDEN_GATE_BRIDGE) // Sets the center of the map to
                // Golden Gate Bridge
                .zoom(17) // Sets the zoom
                .bearing(90) // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
                .tilt(30) // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
                .build(); // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
        break;

    case R.id.menu_addmarker:

        // ---using the default marker---
        /*
         * map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions() .position(GOLDEN_GATE_BRIDGE)
         * .title("Golden Gate Bridge") .snippet("San Francisco")
         * .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
         * .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));
         */

        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(GOLDEN_GATE_BRIDGE)
                .title("Golden Gate Bridge")
                .snippet("San Francisco")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));
        break;

    case R.id.menu_getcurrentlocation:
        // ---get your current location and display a blue dot---
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        break;

    case R.id.menu_showcurrentlocation:
        Location myLocation = map.getMyLocation();
        LatLng myLatLng = new LatLng(myLocation.getLatitude(),
                myLocation.getLongitude());

        CameraPosition myPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(myLatLng).zoom(17).bearing(90).tilt(30).build();
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(myPosition));

        break;

    case R.id.menu_lineconnecttwopoints:
        // ---add a marker at Apple---
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(APPLE)
                .title("Apple")
                .snippet("Cupertino")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));

        // ---draw a line connecting Apple and Golden Gate Bridge---
        map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                .add(GOLDEN_GATE_BRIDGE, APPLE).width(5).color(Color.RED));
        break;
    }

    return true;
}
}
```

I really do think I've tried everything before asking for help here.
(I used to hand-write Z80 assembly code and hand-convert it to Hex in the early 1980's - that was SO simple compared to this........)

Massive thanks for any help from you guys!

added later - here is my error log

```
    05-02 07:33:32.177: I/Google Maps Android API(1058): Google Play services client version: 4323000
05-02 07:33:32.217: I/Google Maps Android API(1058): Google Play services package version: 4324036
05-02 07:33:32.267: D/dalvikvm(1058): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 235K, 9% free 3150K/3452K, paused 27ms, total 28ms
05-02 07:33:32.357: D/AndroidRuntime(1058): Shutting down VM
05-02 07:33:32.357: W/dalvikvm(1058): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1ae4ba8)
05-02 07:33:32.377: E/AndroidRuntime(1058): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-02 07:33:32.377: E/AndroidRuntime(1058): Process: net.learn2develop.googlemaps, PID: 1058
05-02 07:33:32.377: E/AndroidRuntime(1058): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.learn2develop.googlemaps/net.learn2develop.googlemaps.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
05-02 07:33:32.377: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
05-02 07:33:32.377: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
05-02 07:33:32.377: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
05-02 07:33:32.377: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
05-02 07:33:32.377: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-02 07:33:32.377: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-02 07:33:32.377: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-02 07:33:32.377: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-02 07:33:32.377: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-02 07:33:32.377: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-02 07:33:32.377: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-02 07:33:32.377: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-02 07:33:32.377: E/AndroidRuntime(1058): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
05-02 07:33:32.377: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
05-02 07:33:32.377: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
05-02 07:33:32.377: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
05-02 07:33:32.377: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
05-02 07:33:32.377: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
05-02 07:33:32.377: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
05-02 07:33:32.377: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
05-02 07:33:32.377: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):     at net.learn2develop.googlemaps.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)
05-02 07:33:32.377: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
05-02 07:33:32.377: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
05-02 07:33:32.377: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
05-02 07:33:32.377: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):     ... 11 more
05-02 07:33:32.377: E/AndroidRuntime(1058): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: The Maps API requires the additional following permissions to be set in the AndroidManifest.xml to ensure a correct behavior:
05-02 07:33:32.377: E/AndroidRuntime(1058): <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
05-02 07:33:32.377: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):     at maps.e.ci.a(Unknown Source)
05-02 07:33:32.377: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):     at maps.e.ay.a(Unknown Source)
05-02 07:33:32.377: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):     at maps.e.ay.a(Unknown Source)
05-02 07:33:32.377: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):     at maps.e.al.a(Unknown Source)
05-02 07:33:32.377: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):     at maps.e.bh.a(Unknown Source)
05-02 07:33:32.377: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):     at maps.e.bg.a(Unknown Source)
05-02 07:33:32.377: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):     at etu.onTransact(SourceFile:107)
05-02 07:33:32.377: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):     at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:361)
05-02 07:33:32.377: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$a$a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
05-02 07:33:32.377: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
05-02 07:33:32.377: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a$4.b(Unknown Source)
05-02 07:33:32.377: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
05-02 07:33:32.377: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
05-02 07:33:32.377: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
05-02 07:33:32.377: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1460)
05-02 07:33:32.377: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:884)
05-02 07:33:32.377: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1066)
05-02 07:33:32.377: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1168)
05-02 07:33:32.377: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:280)
05-02 07:33:32.377: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
05-02 07:33:32.377: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):     ... 21 more
```

Comment: Give permission Access Network state then check and let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 05-02 07:33:32.377: E/AndroidRuntime(1058): Caused by:
>   java.lang.SecurityException: The Maps API requires the additional
>   following permissions to be set in the AndroidManifest.xml to ensure a
>   correct behavior: 05-02 07:33:32.377: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):

You are missing

```
<uses-permission
android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

in manifest file

You have

```
 android:minSdkVersion="19"
```

You need to change this

```
 public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
```

to
     public class MainActivity extends Activity {

You need to use MapFragment

```
 class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
```

Also need to change

```
 map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
        .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

Also you don't need

```
<permission
android:name="net.learn2develop.googlemaps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="net.learn2develop.googlemaps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
```

Comment: are u sure @raghunandan

Comment: @sakir https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2. you can check the docs and if wrong correct me

Comment: he is already declared as "class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"

Comment: @sakir that should be `MapFragment`. pls check docs again. `MapFragment `for api level 12 and above. op has `SupportMapFragment` `class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment`

Comment: oops. have added my error log at end of question. have tried MapFragment before but will try again in case I didn't do it right. Was confuses me is that I had the code working before - perhaps for a different API target - does it make that much difference??. After 8hrs typing I'll get some air first! Many thanks again

Comment: @user3503656 api level does make difference as api level 11 and below you need to use `SupportMapFragment`. In your case its 19 so `MapFragment` ALso you are missing a permission in manifest file

Comment: @user3503656 you can read the lint warning `@SuppressWarnings("unused")`

Comment: @Raghunandan - you are the Man! - It worked!! Got some funny errors about 'Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.gsf.gservices' but then seemed to go away anyway (bit strange). I presume that I could change the target API to anything from api level 12 upwards without problems? I am so grateful for your help today. If the app is ever finished and on the play store I will give you a credit! - Thanks Chris